# How to check a Python script's the correct version automatically while the shebang is not accurate?

Tags: python

For example, I find [download_model_binary.py](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/scripts/download_model_binary.py)'s shebang is wrong while it contains a Python 2 library function `urllib.urlretrieve`.

I try to use two python interpreters to execute the file and watch its return value in script, but it will lead side effect.

Note: I am asking how detect the correct version of a existing Python 2 script like `download_model_binary.py` which has the wrong shebang, not how to rewrite it to be compatible.

Comment: Since the script wants `python` and not `python3`, it should be a Python 2.x script. This is in accordance with [PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). Granted, this is not true in practice everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
     from urllib import urlretrieve
else:
     from urllib.request import urlretrieve
```

And later use:

```
urlretrieve(frontmatter['caffemodel_url'], model_filename, reporthook)
```

If you need this often consider using [Python Future](http://python-future.org/index.html). It offers a [good solution](http://python-future.org/quickstart.html#standard-library-reorganization) for this type of problem.

Comment: You misunderstand my question, I am asking how detect the version of a existing Python script, not how to rewrite the Python script.

Comment: Well, `sys.version_info.major` gives you the version. Please add more information and examples to your question.